# listView с бесконечной загрузкой

Tags: android

подскажите, как реализовать ListView так, чтобы, когда доходишь до последнего элемента, в список подгружалось еще некоторое количество записей

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В адаптере, как только выполняется `getView()` для последнего элемента списка, загружайте новую порцию элементов, добавляйте их в адаптер, и вызывайте `notifyDataSetChanged()` у адаптера.